# How to handle complex relationships when creating odata API?

Tags: rest, odata, restful-architecture, restful-url, api-design

I am building an Asp.Net web API for a third party product and am considering using OData 4 for my API. I have a fair amount of freedom in my object model but can't change the underlying data model.

I understand that odata supports Navigation Properties for defining relationships, but they seem to be direct links between objects only. In many cases in the data model I'm building on a relationship has its own properties. For example, a 'User' has a collection of 'Member Of' relationships with Groups, Organisational Units etc, and the 'Member Of' link itself has an 'Is Default' boolean property. In some cases, relationships have multiple properties.

Is there a best way to handle this? Do I need to make a 'Membership' entity with properties and have two hops from a User with Navigation Properties (User > Membership > Group)? Should I make a 'Membership' complex type, create a 'Memberships' property which is a collection of 'Membership' and have a Navigation Property on the 'Membership' (if that's possible)? With either of these options should I also add a read-only Navigation Property to all member of Groups for convenience (User > Group)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a REST perspective (see the [Richardson Maturity Model level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3)), once navigating to a `user` resource, the client could discover a `group-query` relationship (link). Here's how this might look in a tool like [HAL Browser](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal-browser):

```
"api:group-query": {
  "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group?userId=1,pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sort={sort}"
},
```

This would take the consumer to a (paged) collection of `group` resources that the user is a member of:

`GET /api/user/1/groups`

which could return something like this:

```
{
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Test Group"
      }, 
      {
        "id": 134,
        "name": "Tennis squad"
      }
    ]
}
```

I see no need for a `membership` resource/entity if you integrate links.

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. My question is about where the links between users and groups have properties though which I don't think your answer addresses.

Comment: looking at the Web Linking specification regarding [Target Attributes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#section-5.4), it looks like you should be able to [extend](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#section-6.3) them with application-specific data.